# custom AngularJS Directive won't draw properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to wrap the angular select list into a simple directive that will allow me to draw a select list and a label both together.

I am encountering two problems.

1.The select list options are not populating

2.The ngModel attribute that I try to pass down into my directive does not populate with the data that I indicate in my directive tag attribute.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.currentBusinessStructure = '';

    $scope.businessStructure = ['Monarchy', 'Corporation'];
}]);

myApp.directive('specialSelect', [function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,

    template:
               '<label ng-transclude></label> \
                <select ng-model="currentBusinessStructure" ng-options="{{ngOptions}}" class="form-control"> \
                </select> \
                <br>INSIDE MY DIRECTIVE: {{ngModel}} : {{ngOptions}}',
    scope: {
        ngOptions: '@ngOption',
        ngModel: '='
    }
};
}]);
```

Please check out my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ou29ted/2/)

Comment: I believe you need to use ngOptions : '=ngOption' without the @

Comment: Sorry, totally misread that. I think your ngOptions expression is wrong. it needs to be a fully qualified expression I believe.Check out this doc. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0):

Try this, finally. Sorry I didn't do this first.

```
    <select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="label for label in ngOptions" class="form-control">
```

And your div should be

```
        <div special-select ng-model="currentBusinessStructure" ng-option="businessStructure">How is your business structured?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In my directive template, I would expand an angular expression as the argument for the ng-options directive in my select list.  However, my directive did not have access to the variable I was using to build my ng-options list.  I needed to pass that variable down in to my directive scope (I chose to call it data), and I had to that local name (data) in my angular expression:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.currentBusinessStructure = 'Monarchy';

    $scope.businessStructure = ['Monarchy', 'Corporation'];
}]);

myApp.directive('specialSelect', [function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,

    template: '<label ng-transclude></label> \
                <select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="{{ngOptions}}" class="form-control"> \
                </select> ',
    scope: {
        ngOptions: '@ngOption',
        ngModel: '=',
        data: '='
    }
};
}]);

<!--in html-->
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div special-select ng-model="currentBusinessStructure" ng-option="item for item in data" data="businessStructure">How is your business structured?</div>
</div>
```